# Взаимодействие с периферийными устройствами через WIN API

Tags: winapi, usb

возникла необходимость получить информацию о USB-устройствах подключенных к ПК.

подскажите, как можно узнать: имя устройства, тип, версию драйверов, дату подключения или где можно найти подобную информацию?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, в Windows лично мне известны всего 4 способа получения информации об USB-девайсах. Если кто-то подскажет ещё - буду благодарен:

1. Читать из ветки реестра [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB]. Для этого есть **advapi32.dll** и её функции типа `RegOpenKey() + RegQueryValue()`. Это ручной разбор древа реестра, поэтому с кроссплатформенностью могут возникнуть проблемы.
2. Более предпочтительный вариант - библиотека **setupapi.dll** с триадой её функций. Первая `SetupDiGetClassDevs()`, которой нужно передать аргумент **GUID_DEVCLASS_USB**. Вторая `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()` будет перечислять все USB, включая контролёры, хабы и их устройства. При помощи третьей `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()` можно будет вытягивать уже порядка 64 различных свойств найденных девайсов.
3. Прямое обращение к контролёру самого USB-устройства, с запросом на чтение его *"дескрипторов"*. Производитель зашивает в них базовые сведения о своём продукте, вплоть до кол-ва конечных точек "Endpoint", их свойств, требуемой пропускной способности шины, мощности питания в мА, и многое другое (этой инфы нет в системном реестре). Для этого нужно будет найти хаб, к которому подключено устройство, открыть его через `CreateFile()`, и посредством `DeviceIoControl()` с кодом **IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION** отправить ему соответствующий "пакет-запроса".
4. Функции из специальной либы **WinUsb.dll**. На сайте MSDN сказано, что данная библиотека была введена для устройств, у которых нет класс-драйвера (типа Storage, HID, etc), т.е. они не расспознаются в системе. В этом случае ОС подгружает драйвер WinUsb.sys и появляется возможность хоть как-то общаться с устройством. К примеру на моей Win-7 этот драйвер не загружается при включении машины (хотя в наличии имеется), поэтому я не могу вызывать напрямую функции из библиотеки WinUsb.dll, пока не подгружу привязанный к ней дров.